# Image isn't updating in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

So i have the following scripts:

```
<?php
//Posts variables
$post_id = 0;
$isEditingPost = false;
$published = 0;
$title = "";
$post_slug = "";
$body = "";
$featured_image = "";
$post_topic = "";

//Get all posts
function getAllPosts(){
    global $conn;

    if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Admin") {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts";
    }elseif($_SESSION['user']['role'] == "Author"){
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=$user_id";
    }
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$posts = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$final_posts = array();
foreach($posts as $post){
    $post['author'] = getPostAuthorById($post['user_id']);
    array_push($final_posts,$post);
}
return $final_posts;

}

function getPostAuthorById($user_id){
    global $conn;

    $sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=$user_id";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if($result){
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)['username'];
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - 
-  Post actions
- - - - - - - - - - -*/
// if user clicks the create post button
if (isset($_POST['create_post'])) { createPost($_POST); }
// if user clicks the Edit post button
if (isset($_GET['edit-post'])) {
    $isEditingPost = true;
    $post_id = $_GET['edit-post'];
    editPost($post_id);
}
// if user clicks the update post button
if (isset($_POST['update_post'])) {
    updatePost($_POST);
}
// if user clicks the Delete post button
if (isset($_GET['delete-post'])) {
    $post_id = $_GET['delete-post'];
    deletePost($post_id);
}

/* - - - - - - - - - - 
-  Post functions
- - - - - - - - - - -*/
function createPost($request_values)
    {
        global $conn,$user_id, $errors, $title, $featured_image, $topic_id, $body, $published;
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
        $title = esc($request_values['title']);
        $body = htmlentities(esc($request_values['body']));
        if (isset($request_values['topic_id'])) {
            $topic_id = esc($request_values['topic_id']);
        }
        if (isset($request_values['publish'])) {
            $published = esc($request_values['publish']);
        }
        // create slug: if title is "The Storm Is Over", return "the-storm-is-over" as slug
        $post_slug = makeSlug($title);
        // validate form
        if (empty($title)) { array_push($errors, "Post title is required"); }
        if (empty($body)) { array_push($errors, "Post body is required"); }
        if (empty($topic_id)) { array_push($errors, "Post topic is required"); }
        // Get image name
        $featured_image = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
        if (empty($featured_image)) { array_push($errors, "Featured image is required"); }
        // image file directory
        $target = "../static/images/" . basename($featured_image);
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
            array_push($errors, "Failed to upload image. Please check file settings for your server");
        }
        // Ensure that no post is saved twice. 
        $post_check_query = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE slug='$post_slug' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $post_check_query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // if post exists
            array_push($errors, "A post already exists with that title.");
        }
        // create post if there are no errors in the form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $query = "INSERT INTO posts (user_id, title, slug, image, body, published, created_at, updated_at) VALUES($user_id, '$title', '$post_slug', '$featured_image', '$body', $published, now(), now())";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ // if post created successfully
                $inserted_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                // create relationship between post and topic
                $sql = "INSERT INTO post_topic (post_id, topic_id) VALUES($inserted_post_id, $topic_id)";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

                $_SESSION['message'] = "Post created successfully";
                header('location: posts.php');
                exit(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
    * - Takes post id as parameter
    * - Fetches the post from database
    * - sets post fields on form for editing
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
    function editPost($role_id)
    {
        global $conn, $title, $post_slug, $body, $published, $isEditingPost, $post_id;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id=$role_id LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        // set form values on the form to be updated
        $title = $post['title'];
        $body = $post['body'];
        $published = $post['published'];
    }

    function updatePost($request_values)
    {
        global $conn, $errors, $post_id, $title, $featured_image, $topic_id, $body, $published;

        $title = esc($request_values['title']);
        $body = esc($request_values['body']);
        $post_id = esc($request_values['post_id']);
        if (isset($request_values['topic_id'])) {
            $topic_id = esc($request_values['topic_id']);
        }
        // create slug: if title is "The Storm Is Over", return "the-storm-is-over" as slug
        $post_slug = makeSlug($title);

        if (empty($title)) { array_push($errors, "Post title is required"); }
        if (empty($body)) { array_push($errors, "Post body is required"); }
        // if new featured image has been provided
        if (isset($_POST['featured_image'])) {
        // Get image name
        $featured_image = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
            // image file directory
            $target = "../static/images/" . basename($featured_image);
            if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['featured_image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                array_push($errors, "Failed to upload image. Please check file settings for your server");
            }
        }

        // register topic if there are no errors in the form
        if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $query = "UPDATE posts SET title='$title', slug='$post_slug', views=0, image='$featured_image', body='$body', published=$published, updated_at=now() WHERE id=$post_id";
            // attach topic to post on post_topic table
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){ // if post created successfully
                if (isset($topic_id)) {
                    $inserted_post_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                    // create relationship between post and topic
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO post_topic (post_id, topic_id) VALUES($inserted_post_id, $topic_id)";
                    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                    $_SESSION['message'] = "Post created successfully";
                    header('location: posts.php');
                    exit(0);
                }
            }
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Post updated successfully";
            header('location: posts.php');
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    // delete blog post
    function deletePost($post_id)
    {
        global $conn;
        $sql = "DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=$post_id";
        if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Post successfully deleted";
            header("location: posts.php");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    
    // if user clicks the publish post button
if (isset($_GET['publish']) || isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
    $message = "";
    if (isset($_GET['publish'])) {
        $message = "Post published successfully";
        $post_id = $_GET['publish'];
    } else if (isset($_GET['unpublish'])) {
        $message = "Post successfully unpublished";
        $post_id = $_GET['unpublish'];
    }
    togglePublishPost($post_id, $message);
}
// delete blog post
function togglePublishPost($post_id, $message)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "UPDATE posts SET published=!published WHERE id=$post_id";
    
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
        header("location: posts.php");
        exit(0);
    }
}

?>
```

Everything works fine , it updates the topic , the post body,title,published state but the image isn't updating , even tho when i create a new post the image is being inserted in the database , when i try to update , the image column in database remains empty.

Here is the create_post.php

```
<?php  include('../config.php'); ?>
<?php  include(ROOT_PATH . '/admin/includes/admin_functions.php'); ?>
<?php  include(ROOT_PATH . '/admin/includes/post_functions.php'); ?>
<?php include(ROOT_PATH . '/admin/includes/header.php'); ?>
<!-- Get all topics -->
<?php $topics = getAllTopics(); ?>
<title>Admin | Create Post</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- admin navbar -->
    <?php include(ROOT_PATH . '/admin/includes/navbar.php') ?>

    <div class="container content">
        <!-- Left side menu -->
        <?php include(ROOT_PATH . '/admin/includes/menu.php') ?>

        <!-- Middle form - to create and edit  -->
        <div class="action create-post-div">
            <h1 class="page-title">Create/Edit Post</h1>
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo BASE_URL . 'admin/create_post.php'?>">
                <?php include(ROOT_PATH . '/includes/errors.php') ?>

                <?php if($isEditingPost == true):?>
                <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id; ?>">
                <?php endif ?>
                <input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" placeholder="Title">
                <label style="float: left; margin: 5px auto 5px;">Featured image</label>
                <input type="file" name="featured_image">
                <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $body; ?></textarea>
                <select name="topic_id">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Choose topic</option>
                    <?php foreach ($topics as $topic): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $topic['id']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $topic['name']; ?>
                    </option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>

                <?php if($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'Admin'):?>
                <?php if($published == true):?>
                <label for="publish">
                    Publish
                    <input type="checkbox" value='1' name="publish" checked="checked">&nbsp;
                </label>
                <?php else:?>
                <label for="publish">
                    Publish
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="publish">&nbsp;
                </label>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php endif ?>
                <?php if ($isEditingPost === true): ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="update_post">UPDATE</button>
                <?php else: ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn" name="create_post">Save Post</button>
                <?php endif ?>
            </form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('body');
</script>
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped input values.

Comment: i know it's vulnerable that's why im doing it on localhost , it's my first project in php and after i finish the logic part i will work on the safety of the data. For now i have another problem

Comment: "after i finish the logic part i will work on the safety of the data"...this is a bad approach because a) re-writing it to be safe involves changing all the SQL code. So basically you'll get it "working", and then have to re-write significant parts of it, and so will have to test it all over again. What a waste of time. It's not hard to write it the safe way in the first place. And b) as I've said already, the same vulnerabilities could also be leading to SQL syntax errors preventing the queries from executing. So actually, writing safe queries might possibly even solve your main problem.

Comment: Therefore, I strongly suggest you focus on writing your queries the correct way, and then worry about testing the overall logic later. You're trying to put the roof on the house, but you haven't created the foundations properly yet.

Comment: I have tried to change a simple query statement where i update a table in database and i am already having an error

Comment: then maybe you didn't do it properly. If you don't show what you did, and don't explain the error, then you can't expect me to tell you what was wrong.

Comment: nvm , i solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be with your if statement in updatePost function `if (isset($_POST['featured_image'])) {`. Change this like in createPost function

```
$featured_image = $_FILES['featured_image']['name'];
if (empty($featured_image)) {
 ...
}
```

Check also https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php for more information about checking uploaded files.

Comment: :)) How silly of me , and i was watching this line of code from create post function for a while but didn't try to make it alike. Thank you